# xxx.layer insertSublayer:buttonALayer atIndex:1 not working in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa

Just as the Headline states. I have two Storyboard, one for iPhone and one for IPad. iPhone works, iPad not. I can access the buttons, for example i can do setTitle for iPad and iOS, but when i execute insertSublayer, this only works for iPhone.

Any suggestions what the reason could be?

Thanks guys!

Edit:

```
UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(228/255.0) green:(91/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:(1.0)];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(152/255.0) green:(61/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:(1.0)];
NSNumber *stopOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
NSNumber *stopTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, nil];
CAGradientLayer *buttonALayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
buttonALayer.frame = startGame.layer.bounds;

float iOSversion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
int layerIndex = 1;
if (iOSversion < 5.9)
{
    layerIndex = 0;
}

float cornerRadius = 0.0f;

buttonALayer.colors = colorsA;
buttonALayer.locations = locations;
buttonALayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
[startGame.layer insertSublayer:buttonALayer atIndex:layerIndex];
```

<- This Code works for iPhone, but not for iPad. The following code works for both devices (Simulator!):

```
[startGame setTitle:@"Bullwaste" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

<- Because it also works for iPad, for me it seems Outlets and references cannot be the reason?

Edit 2:

I tried to do the following:

```
startGame.alpha = 0.3;
NSString *justAString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", startGame.bounds.size.width];
[startGame setTitle:justAString forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Reaction in iPhone Sim: Button goes transparent and title is 280.0000
Reaction in iPad Sim: Button goes transparent and title is 0.00000

I just don't understand this? startGame.alpha does work startGame.bounds.size.width only works in iPhone!?!?

Comment: you should give more details, preferably code. did you check the outlet connections between the vc and ipad storyboard, this would be my first guess as the source of problems

Comment: I edited my post above...

Comment: Define "not works" - you don't see anything, or the layer is not added?

Comment: in iPhone Simulator, the color of the button is changed according to the code. In the iPad Simulator, it stays the same as in the Storyboard (in this case: white color).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, I cannot belief the solution, but:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

I had my code in viewDidLoad, but the view wasn't fully loaded - not for iPad.

What do you think about the solution above, or should I just put in all my code into viewDidAppear? But I don't think calling viewDidLoad twice is a problem and I could belief that some users would see flickering or something like this if i change the button colors on "faster" systems!?

Comment: This is not the solution. You don't call viewDidLoad yourself. You perhaps need to move some of the code you have in viewDidLoad into a later method.

Comment: Of course, I created a subFunction colorizeButtons and called this sub function from viewDidLoad and also from viewDidLoad. In the next step, I dismissed doing gradient buttons and instead switched to using image backgrounds, because I wanted more than just simple gradients ;)